# What am I doing wrong with my HTML/CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the background-size property to work- but- I think there is something I'm doing wrong with my CSS preventing it from working in the first place.  I need to figure out how the CSS image should be displayed- and once it does get displayed- I want to be able to write the text over it.  A little help here?

```xml
<html>
        <head>
         <title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
        <style>

        h3.start{color:  #8391E1; background-color:  #black;, border:  1px; font-size:  100px; float: left font-size:  20px; box-shadow:  2px 2px; line-height: 200px;}
        p {color:  #DD8797; font-size:  32px; line-height:  200%; padding:  5px; width:  300; padding:  10px 0 px 0 px 10px; float: left; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  width:  500px; margin:  5px; display: inline; transform:scale(1,1);  behavior: url(ie-css3.htc); :scale(3,1); z-index:100; left: 250px; top: 350px;}}
    p.ex{height:  200px; width:  200px;} 
        p.test{width: 700px; height:  300px;
    border:  1px dashed #000000;
    word-break:  break-all;}
        #image {
        background:url(https://caronedmunds.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/old-paper21.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding:15px;
    text-align:  left; behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);}
        #image2{background-size:  500px 700px;}
        #text { position:  relative;color:red;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;}
        body {background-color:  #87DDA2;}
         </style>
        </head>
        body
         <h3 class="start">Lord of the Rings:  the Fellowship of the Ring</h3>
        <DIV ID="image">
        <div id="image 2">    p The Lord of the Rings the Fellowship of the Rings was a great movie.  When I was younger I
    tried watching it but I wasn't able to get everything that was going on.  Coupled with the fact that I didn't know what the Hobbit was, it was clear, that I didn't understand it.  That said, I'm a lot older now, and, I'm better able to appreciate it, so, let's see why this film is such a good film shall we?       </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a HTML Validator or a good text editor?

Comment: Your `body` tag is not a `<body>` tag (no brackets), same for the `p` -- What is the problem with the fixed version? http://jsfiddle.net/uyjaydbk/

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that "#black" is valid. It should either hold the value of "black" or "#000000." Also, like Alex said, you're body tag is broken.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are a lot of errors in your HTML code syntax:

- Use black instead of #black for css-colors
- Your body tag doesn't have brackets `<body>` neither does your `<p>` tag

They have explained easily on https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/ how to write text over your images.

Comment: I think I may have figured out what was wrong with it.  I was trying to get my css to expand the image over the whole page.  I wasn't doing the background css correctly.  I ended up doing repeat instead of enlarging it.  I figured out also what I need to do to get the image to work on external css (I can't use the space) and for my future pages I have just enlarged it a lot.  I know that some tags are missing but that was for the purposes of this board so it wouldn't show up in html.  Either way it's fixed now.

Comment: Ok, I'm happy u have find a solution

Comment: I also think that I saw the #black thing and corrected it I think.  I didn't realize before that it was my syntax.  It's no wonder I was frustrated.